# How to using implicit flow keycloak with react native?

Tags: react-native, single-sign-on, keycloak, access-token

- I need to get access_token from Keycloak.
- Currently, I am getting **grant_type** = **client_credentials** and client_id, client_secret;
- But due to some system requirements, we need to use **implicit** flow. But I can't get the password so I can't get the token with **grant_type** = **password**.
- I use react native and am using curl to get tokens.
- Is there any solution that can help me? Please